# Is there a direct link between CaseComment and FeedItem records?

Tags: record, feeditem, case-comment

Trying to find a way to link FeedItem records to the CaseComment they are related to. Have a Lightning Component pulling in Case information, but failing to find a reliable way to relate the replies to CaseComments which are listed as FeedComments under FeedItems. Is there a way to reliably associate the FeedItems back to the CaseComment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how to go about it. There's no link between the CaseComment records and the FeedItem records that can be accessed via the usual SOQL route. What you can do instead is make use of the [Connect in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectAPI_overview.htm) functionality which makes calls via the [ConnectApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_connect_api.htm).

The [ChatterFeeds](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm) sub-class has methods to call out to the API which returns both FeedItems (and in this case more specifically their parent [FeedElement](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_connectapi_output_feed_element.htm) object) and it's associated CaseComment data with a bit of related data digging. You can access the CaseComment data via the FeedElement.capabilities field which gives you access to [FeedElementCapabilities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_connectapi_output_feed_element_capabilities.htm) class. This then gives you access to the FeedElementCapabilities.caseComment field (if the FeedElement has that capability, as in it's querying a CaseComment) which returns the [CaseCommentCapability](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_connectapi_output_case_comment_capability.htm#apex_connectapi_output_case_comment_capability) class which then has the CaseComment data.

Overall structure is something like:

- ConnectApi

  - ChatterFeeds (Use method to get collection of FeedElement)

    - FeedElement

      - FeedElementCapabilities

        - CaseCommentCapability (desired CaseComment data here)

For my usage, I did a SOQL query for the limited set of FeedItem records I wanted from a Case and then used that to build an Id collection for retrieving from the ConnectApi via the [ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementBatch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_getFeedElementBatch_1) method.

```java
    //Get relevant FeedItem data, used this since I have additional LIMIT and OFFSET requirements plus additional sub-query data I wanted
    List<FeedItem> feedItemList = [
      SELECT Id, Type, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate,
      (SELECT FeedItemId, CommentBody, CommentType, RelatedRecordId, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name FROM FeedComments ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC)
      FROM FeedItem 
      WHERE ParentId = :caseId 
      AND Type = 'CaseCommentPost'
      ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC 
      LIMIT :limitValue 
      OFFSET :offsetValue
    ];
    
    //Build collection of Ids
    List<String> feedItemIdList = new List<String>();
    for(FeedItem fi : feedItemList) {
      feedItemIdList.add(fi.Id);
    }
    
    //Get ConnectApi data
    Map<Id, ConnectApi.FeedElement> feedElementMap = new Map<Id, ConnectApi.FeedElement>();
    List<ConnectApi.BatchResult> batchResultList = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementBatch(Network.getNetworkId(), feedItemIdList);
    
    for(ConnectApi.BatchResult batchResult : batchResultList) {
      if(batchResult.isSuccess()) {
        if(batchResult.getResult() instanceof ConnectApi.FeedElement) {
          ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = (ConnectApi.FeedElement) batchResult.getResult();
          feedElementMap.put(feedElement.Id, feedElement); //Will have the same Id as the FeedItem record query
        }
      } else {
        System.debug(batchResult.getErrorMessage());
      }
    }
    
    //Use the data
    for(FeedItem feedItem : feedItemList) {
      ConnectApi.CaseCommentCapability caseCommentCapability = feedElementMap.get(feedItem.Id)?.capabilities?.caseComment;
    
      //Might want to throw the desired data into a custom Wrapper you define to make working with the data easier from that point
      CaseCommentWrapper wrapper = new CaseCommentWrapper(feedItem, caseCommentCapability);
    }
```

Comment: nice; sadly one needs to use SeeAllData=true to unit test ConnectApi, sigh

Comment: @cropredy Yep, testing has ended up being rather annoying with this (especially since getFeedElementBatch isn't one of the supported [setTest methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_setTest_methods)), but at least it's doable with the right setup.